# How to scroll to the next logical page in a ListBox with physical scrolling

Tags: wpf, listbox, scroll

I do have a listbox which must have CanContentScroll==false because i need to be able to scroll it smoothly. This enables physical scrolling.

I also want to scroll the listbox by page, but if i call the PageDown method on the listbox internal ScrollViewer the first row gets cutted because the listbox height is not a multiple of the row height.

I want the first row to be always completely visible, like when using logical scrolling.

Can someone give me a hint on how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get the same effect for a non virtualizing `ItemsControl` (`ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"`) as for a virtualizing one if you scroll down and then select the upper visible container with the mouse. This can also be done in code.

When `CanContentScroll` is set to false, virtualizing is turned off so all containers will be generated at all times. To get the top visible container we can iterate the containers from the top until we reach the `VerticalOffset` of the `ScrollViewer`. Once we got it we can simply call `BringIntoView` on it and it will align nicely at the top just like it would if virtualization was being used.

*Example*

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}"
         ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
         ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="listBox_ScrollChanged" >
```

*Call `BringIntoView` on the top visible container in the event handler*

```
private void listBox_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ItemsControl itemsControl = sender as ItemsControl;
    ScrollViewer scrollViewer = e.OriginalSource as ScrollViewer;
    FrameworkElement lastElement = null;
    foreach (object obj in itemsControl.Items)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(obj) as FrameworkElement;
        double offset = element.TransformToAncestor(scrollViewer).Transform(new Point(0, 0)).Y + scrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
        if (offset > e.VerticalOffset)
        {
            if (lastElement != null)
                lastElement.BringIntoView();
            break;
        }
        lastElement = element;
    }
}
```

---

To only achieve this effect when you want to call `PageDown`, in a Button click for example, you can create an extension method for `ListBox` called `LogicalPageDown`.

```
listBox.LogicalPageDown();
```

*ListBoxExtensions*

```
public static class ListBoxExtensions
{
    public static void LogicalPageDown(this ListBox listBox)
    {
        ScrollViewer scrollViewer = VisualTreeHelpers.GetVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(listBox);
        ScrollChangedEventHandler scrollChangedHandler = null;
        scrollChangedHandler = (object sender2, ScrollChangedEventArgs e2) =>
        {
            scrollViewer.ScrollChanged -= scrollChangedHandler;
            FrameworkElement lastElement = null;
            foreach (object obj in listBox.Items)
            {
                FrameworkElement element = listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(obj) as FrameworkElement;
                double offset = element.TransformToAncestor(scrollViewer).Transform(new Point(0, 0)).Y + scrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
                if (offset > scrollViewer.VerticalOffset)
                {
                    if (lastElement != null)
                        lastElement.BringIntoView();
                    break;
                }
                lastElement = element;
            }
        };
        scrollViewer.ScrollChanged += scrollChangedHandler;
        scrollViewer.PageDown();
    }
}
```

I noticed in your question that you already got the `ScrollViewer` but I'm adding an implementation to `GetVisualChild` if anyone else comes across this question

```
public static T GetVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject parent) where T : Visual
{
    T child = default(T);

    int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
    {
        Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        child = v as T;
        if (child == null)
        {
            child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
        }
        if (child != null)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return child;
}
```

Comment: @Zmaster: Forgot that `Margin` etc. can be involved when finding the relative position of the container. Updated my answer accordingly

Comment: At the end i decided to use use ScrollToOffset() by calculating the target offset with the assumption that every item has the same height (this is my case). It's more efficient than iterating the items. Your solution on the other hand also works on different items height, so i accepted it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you scroll the top item of the "new page" into view, would that achieve what you're looking for? 
See [ScrollIntoView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.scrollintoview%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Comment: I think that the item would appear to the bottom on the listbox instead of the top. Also, i have no idea how to identify that item.